# If There is no connection Software Cannot Open

Tags: c#

I'm using this script to update news every time I change it in the txt file:

```
public Form1()
{ 
    InitializeComponent();
    string n = wc.DownloadString("https://www.dropbox.com/s/znog54omhbhxwej/n.txt?dl=1");
    NEWS.Text = n;
}
```

But when there is no connection I can't open the software.
I need help ....

Comment: Uhm, what? Please explain yourself a little better

Comment: You are attempting a long-running, external operation from the constructor.  The constructor should only be used to initialize fields.  Why don't you try to load the connection *after* the form has loaded.  And if it fails, display a message to the user.  I would even kick off another thread with an `await` from `Form1_Load` that tries the connection so the user isn't stuck with a frozen UI while the connection is attempted.

Answer (score 0):

I think because there is no connection your code is throwing an WebException.

Try do this.

```
public Form1()
{ 
    try 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string n = wc.DownloadString("https://www.dropbox.com/s/znog54omhbhxwej/n.txt?dl=1");
        NEWS.Text = n;
    }
    catch (WebException wEx) 
    {
         MessageBox.Show("No internet connection");  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with this:

```
public Form1()
{ 
    InitializeComponent();
    try
      { string n = wc.DownloadString("https://xxxxx?dl=1");
    NEWS.Text = n;
      }
    catch(Exception objException)
      { System.Diagnostics.WriteLine(objExceptio.Message);
      }
}
```

Anyway, I would do it in the treatment of form's Load event